# Remastersys creating 36k ISO files 14.10/15.04/15.10

Tags: 15.04, 15.10, 14.10, iso, remastersys

Remastersys has been creating unusually small ISO files, I observed this issue starting on Ubuntu 14.10 but this also happens on 15.04, 15.10, and even the daily builds of 16.04 LTS. This [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2284988) (Which I am 99% sure that it is my problem) here suggests how to fix the problem, but I do not know how to install the syslinux-utils and isolinux packages onto the ISO manually, so how do I do this? I would use Systemback but I do not want to backup my entire system and compress it into an ISO I just want to create a custom distro essentially to use around the house and share with my friends.

Comment: You should know remastersys is a discontinued project, not supported anymore.

Comment: Use Rinzwind's answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/49679/158442

Comment: @muru will this take all of my changes on my current system and turn it into a distro iso?

Comment: @davidbuddy9 you'll need to adapt the steps a bit, but you can do it. Essentially, skip the customizing and make a a squashfs image of your root filesystem (mounted again elsewhere for ease of use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I figured out that if you need to install syslinux-utils and isolinux packages onto the main system and not the ISO. For some reason when installing Remastersys these two packages are not installed with it but it is needed if you want Remastersys to make fully functioning ISO files.